# Is the definition of hyperparameter C in SVR opposite to the corresponding C in SVM?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, libsvm, regsvr32

I just realized that support vector machine can be used for regression thanks to the [nice article](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introduction-to-support-vector-regression-svr-a3ebc1672c2) However, I am quite confused with the definition of the hyperparameter C.

I am well aware of the slack variables \xi_i associated with each data point and the hyperparameter C in classification SVM. There, the objective function is
\min_{w, b} \frac{|w|}{2} + C\sum_{i=1}^N \xi_i,  such that

y_i (w \cdot x_i + b) \ge 1 - \xi_i and \xi_i \ge 0.

In SVM, the larger C is, the larger the penalty and hence soft SVM reduces to hard SVM as C goes to infinity. (sorry for the raw latex code, i remember latex is supported but it seems not the case)

From the linked article, the objective function and the constraints are as follows
[image]
I think the equations also imply that the larger C is, the larger the penalty. However, the author of the article claims the opposite,
[image]

I noticed that someone asked the author the same question at the end of the article but there has been no response.

I guess there might be a typo in the equation, so I looked for support from any reference and then I found that [SVR in Python](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) uses the same convention that the strength of regularization is inversely proportional to C. I tried to check the source code of SVR but I can't find any formula. Can someone help resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

C is regularization parameter, which means its before the square of W, not before the relaxation, so the C parameter may be equal to 1/C.